# Выдает ошибку, перепробовала все варианты с этого сайта. self.txt_phone.insert(END, sd[1]) IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Выдает ошибку `self.txt_phone.insert(END, sd[1]) IndexError: string index out of range`
как можно исправить код?

```
import sqlite3
    def usersData():
        con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    phone CHAR(11),
                    name TEXT,
                    surname TEXT,
                    birthdate TEXT)""")
        
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    ...

    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.messagebox
    import proverka
    from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
    from tkinter import messagebox as mb
    
    class Users:
        def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title("Записная книжка")
            self.root.geometry('1800x800+40+0')
            self.root.config(bg='black')
    
            id = StringVar()
            phone = StringVar()
            name = StringVar()
            surname = StringVar()
            birthdate = StringVar()
    
            ...
    
            def UsersRecords(event):
                global sd
                searchUsr = userslist.curselection()[0]
                sd = userslist.get(searchUsr)
    
                self.txt_id.delete(0, END)
                self.txt_id.insert(END, sd[0])
                self.txt_phone.delete(0, END)
                self.txt_phone.insert(END, sd[1])
                self.txt_name.delete(0, END)
                self.txt_name.insert(END, sd[2])
                self.txt_surname.delete(0, END)
                self.txt_surname.insert(END, sd[3])
                self.txt_birthdate.delete(0, END)
                self.txt_birthdate.insert(END, sd[4])
```

Comment: `print(sd)` что выдает?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заместо 1 поставить 0

```
self.txt_phone.insert(END, sd[0])
```